# set default mock location data at DDMS

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ddms

When using DDMS in eclipse to simulate location data I manually input the lat/lng value. Can I set default values for them so that I don't have to do it over after restarting my eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create command line batch file that will fix geo location. You can read how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#console).

Update:

I've searched through the source codes of ddmlib. We can only laugh from the comment:

```
public class EmulatorControlPanel extends SelectionDependentPanel {

    // default location: Patio outside Charlie's
    private final static double DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = -122.084095;
    private final static double DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 37.422006;
```

However, if you want you can change this values and rebuild the sources. This class is situated here:

```
android/sdk/ddms/libs/ddmlib/src/com/android/ddmlib/EmulatorConsole.java
```

I'm not very good at reflection, maybe it is possible to change this values through it.

I'm not sure but I think it is possible to add ddmlib.jar to your application and in your application set the values for yours location.

Good luck! If you manage to do this, please, write about your experience!

Comment: well, a batch file will do but isn't there a way to set the default value once and forever? Where does the default value in DDMS come from?